# LibGDX GLSL Apply to background

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I want to apply a shader to the whole screen using GLSL in my libGDX game.
To clear the background with a color, I'm using

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, 1f);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

However, when I apply my shader to the stage's spritebatch:

```
stage.getBatch().setShader(shader);
```

... the shader only applies to drawn sprites of the stage, not the whole screen.
I'm using a shader which turns affected pixels red, just for clarity:

[image]

How do I apply my shader to the whole screen?

Comment: You could try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ they might be able to help you better.

Comment: A clear operation in OpenGL does not use shaders. When you want to apply a shader to the background, you'll have to draw a screen-filling sprite and apply the shader to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: shaders only apply to <s>rendered textures</s> rendering.
My background drawing code is now the following:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

batch.begin();
batch.draw(background, 0, 0, width, height);
batch.end();
```

The variable `background` is a 2x2 texture which will fill the whole background.

Comment: "*I figured it out: shaders only apply to rendered textures.*" No, that has nothing to do with textures. Shaders only apply to *rendering*. Clearing an image isn't rendering.

Comment: Whatever you wanna say ;)